# Woocommerce Product Not Show

Tags: php, wordpress, product

I'm insert new products in woocommerce with -> wp insert post

```
        $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_type'  => 'product',
        'tax_input'  => array('product_cat' => 437),
        'post_author'   => 1,

    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Product inserts successfully.

But not showing in shop or archive category page.

Just can show single product page.

I've tried to search in Google.

Comment: Are you sure data is inserted in database. Did you check with database ?

Comment: Yes , post show in search and single product , just not show in category

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `'post_status' => 'publish'` . Try below example.

**Example**

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_type'  => 'product',
    'tax_input'  => array('product_cat' => 437),
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',

);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
```

Comment: im test it , just in search and single.php can see

Comment: @vahidrezaei this is strange, would you please update this same post as backend and check it's displayed or not.

Comment: dude post is ok category taxnomy , for showing in shop and category i must open post and click on update post , i dont change post detail just click on update post and post show in shop

Comment: @vahidrezaei Did you mean you just update post and display this post on shop page right?

Answer (score 0):

The post_category you are using is for core categories taxonomy. For custom taxonomies you have to use tax_input. For example, the next code set terms for custom_tax_category and custom_ta_tag taxonomies.

```
$args = array(
'post_type'     => 'custom_post_type',
'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $title ),
'post_content'  => 'some content',
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'post_author'   => $author_id,
'tax_input'     => array(
                       'custom_tax_category' => array( $category_id ),
                       'custom_tax_tag'      => array( $tag_id )
 ),
);
$new_cpt_id = wp_insert_post( $args );
```